# Multiple glDrawArrays() Calls vs Buffer Updates - Performance

Tags: ios, performance, opengl-es-2.0

I am drawing many similar 2D quads in OpenGL ES2.0 (iOS) using vertex arrays, trying to keep best possible performance. I am aware, that  for performance reasons it is recommended to put all the calculated geometry into a VBO and use the lowest possible number of calls to glDrawArrays().

However, when there are many similar quads, each one transformed in each frame, wouldn't it be faster to create *once* a very small VBO, for example adding just four vertices (or two triangles) into it, and then continue with per frame transformations and a separate glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, **0, 4**) call for each quad ?

In this scenario, I would expect lower data transmission from CPU to GPU and better performance because the VBO contents are small and static. Multiple glDrawArrays() calls would repeatedly redraw the same geometry with a different model-view-projection matrix passed as a uniform. The following code may clarify what I try to do:

```
/// Executed only once:

/// The quad attributes (only position to simplify the example).
NSInteger idx = 0;
attributes[idx++] = -0.5;
attributes[idx++] = -0.5;
attributes[idx++] = 0.5;
attributes[idx++] = -0.5;
attributes[idx++] = -0.5;
attributes[idx++] = 0.5;
attributes[idx++] = 0.5;
attributes[idx++] = 0.5;

/// The buffer data
if(NO == glIsVertexArrayOES(vertexArray)) {
    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &vertexArray);
    glGenBuffers(1, &bufferObject);
}
glBindVertexArrayOES(vertexArray);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferObject);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(attributes), attributes, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);
glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2*sizeof(float), (char *)NULL);

///...

/// Executed per frame:

glBindVertexArrayOES(vertexArray);
for(NSInteger i = 0; i < numQuads; i++) {
   quad = [quads objectAtIndex:i];
   m4 = GLKMatrix4Identity;
   m4 = GLKMatrix4MakeScale(quad.size, quad.size, 1.0);
   m4 = GLKMatrix4Multiply(GLKMatrix4MakeRotation(quad.angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), m4);
   m4 = GLKMatrix4Multiply(GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(quad.position.x, quad.position.y, 0.0), m4);
   modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, m4);
   glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocationMVP, 1, GL_FLASE, modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
   glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

Does this approach may have any performance benefits over a single glDrawArrays() call ?

Comment: The draw call is very expensive.  Avoid calling it multiple times if at all possible.  Imagine drawing a thousand straight lines (of different size and direction) using a thousand draw calls.  The imagine creating a buffer with 2 thousand points and a single draw call.  The passing of data would take the same amount of time, but the drawing would need to lock the screen, draw, then release a thousand times vs once.

Comment: "The passing of data would take the same amount of time" - but using a single, short buffer does not mean reusing it on GPU side, without passing data ?

Comment: I still think that the drawing call takes much more time than passing the information.  I've actually tested this extravagantly with lines and polygons.  Doing one draw call made a vast improvement in speed for me.  Not to say that will always be the case, but in my experience multiple draw calls kills performance.

Comment: Thanks. It seems I may need to reconsider my approach. Besides passing data I was hoping, that adding combined transformations as uniforms to the vertex shader would prevent many geometry calculations on CPU (one matrix instead of six - two triangles). On the other hand my bottleneck is the GPU, not CPU.